# Websocket client not working for wss using python code

Tags: python, websocket, client

I am using python client to connect to a server hosted in azure. I am using websockets to connect. I am passing the auth header in the python client code. The code doesn't work when we give **wss://** url for connection. The error says :

```
Handshake status 403 Forbidden
```

However same thing is working when tested using postman.

Here is the code snippet used to connect to the websocket server:

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Opened connection")

auth_str = "Authorization:Basic abgvrgfrbnfrfurfr"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://uri.com/websocket",
                             header=[auth_str],
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close
                              )
    ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel) 
    rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  
    rel.dispatch()
```

The request headers of the requests in postman and python client have no difference. Don't know why the python client says `403 forbidden`.

It is only working under one condition : Setting HTTPSOnly as false in app service and passing ws:// uri instead of wss://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, your header parameter definition is wrong. It needs to be like

```
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://uri.com/websocket",
                             header={ 'Authorization': 'Basic abgvrgfrbnfrfurfr' },
                              on_open=on_open,
                              on_message=on_message,
                              on_error=on_error,
                              on_close=on_close
                              )
```